# HQL: greatest between two values

Tags: mysql, sql, function, hql

I'm using HQL to query MySQL Database.
I am doing somithing like

```
SELECT function('GREATEST', column1, column2) as greatest from Table
```

beacause I want the greatest value between two values in two different column, but it doesn't work.
How can I use the SQL function `GREATEST` in HQL?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example and expected output?

Comment: @OP: _...somithing like..._ Why can't you post exact one?

Comment: @OP: Did you try [_**GREATEST(value1,value2,...)**_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use case of if instead of greatest

```
case when column1>column2 then column1 else column2 end
```

Comment: You can choose,you can change the case to column1>=column2

Comment: In the first case you will get column2 but you can choose null also for example

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function

```
SELECT GREATEST(column1, column2) as greatest from Table
```